# Running node js on cloudflare pages

Tags: node.js, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

I am using Cloudflare pages for the first time and I've been trying to understand how my node js project should be started.

Usually, when I work on a server, what I would do is `npm install` and then `npm start`. But in Cloudflare pages (serverless) I should run a single command inside the `build command` box (in the Cloudflare UI).

Adding `npm install` to the `start` script of packages.json is not a right solution.

1. What should be a good solution for my situation?
2. Is there a place where I can see actual logs better than what the Cloudflare UI offers?

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare Pages helps you to deploy SPA. So, the build command, it asks for, is used to build the SPA to generate HTML, CSS and JS.